Create interval of data from dataframe with given median
I have a large data frame of subjects. For simplcity's sake I have posted a smaller modified version of my data frame below.
subject   age   sex   
A         5.35  Female
B         5.70  Male
C         6.00  Female
D         6.07  Male
E         6.25  Male
F         6.88  Male
G         7.00  Female
H         7.02  Male
I         7.11  Female
J         8.00  Male
K         8.50  Female

I am writing a function that will input age and tail (and eventually sex using the large data frame I have). The desired output is an interval data frame that is filtered from the data frame with the age input being the median of the interval, and tail being the number of data points on both sides of the median, age input.
df.loc is not entirely what I am looking for. Example functionality is down below:
def interval_set(age = 7, tail = 3):
   # take dataframe above and output below:

Out[1]:

subject   age   sex   
D         6.07  Male
E         6.25  Male
F         6.88  Male
G         7.00  Female
H         7.02  Male
I         7.11  Female
J         8.00  Male

Thanks in advance!

Is 7 supposed to be the median? Or do you want to compute this automatically? ALso should the data ignore sex?

@mozway in the example above, 7 is the median, age=7

and yes, I want it to ignore sex for now. I will be utilizing sex later.

But it could be any value?

@mozway correct. If it's 6 or 8 for example though, it wouldn't work with a tail of 3.

See the answer below if I understood correctly, if not please clarify

If I understand correctly, you want 3 (tail) values before and after the closest value to your target (age, here 7).
You could sort_values, then get the point closest to the target with the abs difference and idxmin, finally select the indices to keep:
def interval_set(df, age=7, tail=3):
    s = df['age'].sort_values()
    idx = np.arange(len(s))-s.sub(age).abs().idxmin()
    return df.loc[s.index[abs(idx)<=tail]]

out = interval_set(df)

Output:
  subject   age     sex
3       D  6.07    Male
4       E  6.25    Male
5       F  6.88    Male
6       G  7.00  Female
7       H  7.02    Male
8       I  7.11  Female
9       J  8.00    Male


shouldn't line 2 in the function (idx=...) have a stop argument? In my larger dataframe, 'm getting all the data points from the smallest age point to the last data point that has the age that would make the median age the median age.

for example: I get an interval with all the data points younger than 11, then data points up to the highest age possible that would make 11 the median when I have 11 as my age and tail=60. Let me know if you want me to share a larger sample.

@florence-y can you provide a reproducible example? The function should output at most 2*tail+1 rows.

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.DataFrame({
    'subject': list('ABCDEFGHIJK'),
    'age': [5.35, 5.70, 6.00, 6.07, 6.25, 6.88, 7.00, 7.02, 7.11, 8.00, 8.50],
    'sex': ['Female', 'Male', 'Female', 'Male', 'Male', 'Male', 'Female', 'Male', 'Female', 'Male', 'Female']
})
print(df)
age = 7
tail = 3

age_numpy = df['age'].to_numpy()
sorted_idx = age_numpy.argsort()
age_diff = np.abs(age_numpy[sorted_idx] - age)
print(age_diff)
# Find the index of the closest age (median) in the sorted array
median_idx = age_diff.argmin()

start_idx = np.clip(median_idx - tail,0,len(df) -1 )
print(start_idx)#3
end_idx   = np.clip(median_idx + tail +1,0,len(df) -1 +1)
print(end_idx)#10
interval_df = df.iloc[sorted_idx[start_idx : end_idx]]
print(interval_df)
"""
  subject   age     sex
3       D  6.07    Male
4       E  6.25    Male
5       F  6.88    Male
6       G  7.00  Female
7       H  7.02    Male
8       I  7.11  Female
9       J  8.00    Male
"""

Method 2 :
  import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.DataFrame({
    'subject': list('ABCDEFGHIJK'),
    'age': [5.35, 5.70, 6.00, 6.07, 6.25, 6.88, 7.00, 7.02, 7.11, 8.00, 8.50],
    'sex': ['Female', 'Male', 'Female', 'Male', 'Male', 'Male', 'Female', 'Male', 'Female', 'Male', 'Female']
})

print(df)

age = 7
tail = 3

# Convert the 'age' column to a NumPy array 
age_numpy = df['age'].to_numpy()

# Find the index of the element in 'age_numpy' closest to 'age'
# This uses absolute difference to find the minimum distance
#The argmin function comes in to find the index within this array 
#of absolute differences that has the minimum value.
median_idx = (np.abs(age_numpy - age)).argmin()
print(median_idx)#6
# Calculate the starting and ending indices for extracting the interval
 # Ensure start_idx is non-negative
start_idx = max(median_idx - tail, 0) 
# Limit end_idx to DataFrame length
end_idx = min(median_idx + tail + 1, len(df)) 

# Extract the DataFrame slice containing the nearest neighbors
interval_df = df.iloc[start_idx:end_idx]

print(interval_df)
"""
  subject   age     sex
3       D  6.07    Male
4       E  6.25    Male
5       F  6.88    Male
6       G  7.00  Female
7       H  7.02    Male
8       I  7.11  Female
9       J  8.00    Male
"""


could you add some words about how this works? also if you have two distinct Answers, feel free to make them two separate Answers!

added a couple of comments. Please check. @ti7
